# RegEx - greedy white space match

Tags: regex

I am trying to determine the correct RegEx syntax to perform the following. I have line in a file in which I want to match every character before the first occurrence of white space.

so for example in the line:

> 123abc xyz foo bar

it is unclear to me why the following:

```
^.*\s
```

is matching up to the b in the word bar:

> 123abc xyz foo

It appears to me that the \s is greedy, however I am not certain how I can make it not greedy and just match 123abc I have tried various forms of this regex in an attempt to make it non-greedy `^.*\s?` or something like this, however I have been unsuccessful. Thank you in advance

Comment: try this - `^.*?\s`. in your version the point is greedy

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted - thank you both - What I thought I was doing was making the point greedy with the * until it finds a blank space (with the \s) and then I would place the ? after the \s to indicate that only match 0 or more times. I understand now - thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is because `.` can be any character, including space. You can try

```
^[^ ]*\s
```

or

```
^\S*\s
```

instead.

That is a greedy re. But you can make non-greedy re also:

```
^.*?\s
```

You mistake is that you have placed `?` on a wrong place.

Examples:

```
$ echo aaaa bbb cccc dddd > re.txt
$ cat re.txt
aaaa bbb cccc dddd
$ egrep -o '^.*\s' re.txt
aaaa bbb cccc 
$ egrep -o '^\S*\s' re.txt
aaaa 
$ egrep -o '^[^ ]*\s' re.txt
aaaa
```

And non-greedy search with perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^(.*?)\s/' re.txt
aaaa
```

Comment: Should be noted that each such match will include exactly one trailing whitespace character

Comment: Thank you Igor - you answered my first question and a different one regarding RegEx - thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use regex `^\S*(?=\s)`

Which mean all (`*`) non whitespace characters (`\S`) from very beginning (`^`), but has to be followed be whitespace character (`\s`), but not included in match - positive lookahead `(?=\s)`

If you want trailing whitespace(s) to be included as well, then use regex `^\S*\s+`